# Is there an R function for plotting weighted (IPTW) cumulative incidence curve for competing risk?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, propensity-score-matching

Since I would like to compare the survival time between treated and untreated groups for an observational data set, I used propensity score weighting method to get IPTW. After this, I want to get cumulative incidence curves (CIFs) for competing risk. I know how to get a non-weigted CIF; however, I could not find a R function for weighted CIF. Thanks for everyone.

**non-weighted CIF**
crr(ftime, fstatus, cov1, cov2, tf, cengroup, failcode=1, cencode=0,
subset, na.action=na.omit, gtol=1e-06, maxiter=10, init, variance=TRUE)

Regards,
Stanley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no R-Package which implements this method so far. I am currently workin on an R-Package that does this sort of stuff (including confidence intervals, hypothesis tests etc.), but it's still under development so I can't share my code yet.

What you could do is the following:
1.) Estimate a parametric competing risks model (Fine & Gray / Cause-Specific-Cox ...)
2.) Use the model to predict the CIF at all event times for every individual
3.) Take a weighted mean (with your IPTW) at each time point inside each of your groups of interest

This procedure is decribed in some papers. See for example [Neumann (2016)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27084321/)

Comment: Thanks R.D. Would you mind letting me know once you publish your R-Package?

Comment: The package is published now under the name `adjustedCurves`. It can be installed directly from the github page: https://github.com/RobinDenz1/adjustedCurves